# Vectorizing for loop using splicing in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I have this for loop:

```
blockSize = 5
ds = np.arange(20)
ds = np.reshape(ds, (1, len(ds))
counts = np.zeros(len(ds[0]/blockSize))

for i in range(len(counts[0])):
    counts[0, i] = np.floor(np.sum(ds[0, i*blockSize:i*blockSize+blockSize]))
```

I am trying to vectorize it, doing something like this:

```
countIndices = np.arange(len(counts[0]))
counts[0, countsIndices] = np.floor(np.sum(ds[0, countIndices*blockSize:countIndices*blockSize + blockSize]))
```

However, this does not work and gives this error:

```
counts[0, countIndices] = np.floor(np.sum(ds[0, countIndices*blockSize:countIndices*blockSize + blockSize]))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I know that something like this works:

```
counts[0, countIndices] = np.floor(ds[0, countIndices*blockSize]
                         + ds[0, countIndices*blockSize + 2] +
                         ... ds[0, countIndices*blockSize + blockSize])
```

The issue is that for large values of blocksize (which blocksize is very large in my actual code), this is not feasible to implement. I am confused as to how to accomplish what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show any and all errors with full traceback. Did you mean `counts = np.zeros(len(ds[0])//blockSize)` instead of `counts = np.zeros(len(ds[0]/blockSize))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do `floor` if you store the result to an integer array. You can also create a fake new axis of size `blockSize` to fully vectorize your operation.

```
block_size = 5
ds = np.arange(80.0).reshape(4, -1)   # Shape (4, 20)
counts = np.empty((ds.shape[0], ds.shape[1] // block_size), dtype=int)
```

To introduce the fake dimension and sum:

```
ds.reshape(ds.shape[0], -1, block_size).sum(axis=-1, out=counts)
```

Reshaping does not copy the data, so the operation `ds.reshape(ds.shape[0], -1, block_size)` is extremely cheap in both time and space.

You can use `-1` for one of the reshape dimensions to avoid computing/writing out long division expressions.